# How to control what happens when a program is iconned in Windows XP

Tags: c++, icons, real-time, state

I have a real-time program that needs to be operating continuously. When the program is iconned, it seems that it sometimes stops updating and other times will abort when it is restored to the active state.  Is there a method of controlling what happens when my program is iconned? I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: What do you mean by "iconned"?

Comment: @Joe: My guess is the System Notification area (System Tray), but it could also be minimised.

Comment: I assume he means icon-ed (minimized)? However if it is really a program that needs to run permanently he may better implement it as a service.

Answer (score 2):

I'm stealing lothar's comment and presenting it as an answer: You may want to implement your real time program as a windows service. If you need to start and stop it under user control, you can provide a GUI (that does not need to run all the time) to start, pause, continue, and stop the service. As a service, your program is much less likely to be interrupted by the user doing thing on the computer, including things like logging out.

Comment: +1 for stealing and doing the work to make it into a real answer ;-)